# Alamofire split nested object while sending Request

Tags: ios, swift

i'm sending follow data on the server

```
params =  ["product": [["product_id": 1, "quantity": 6], ["product_id": 3, "quantity": 7], ["product_id": 4, "quantity": 1]]]
```

```
Alamofire.request("http://localhost/info-c.php", method:.post, parameters: params , headers:  getHeaderForLoggInUser() ).responseJSON { response in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        if let json = JSON(response.result.value ?? [:]).dictionary{
                            print(json)
                            completed(json)
                        }else{
                            dError( "Internal server Error")
                        }
                        break
                    case .failure(let er):
                        dError( "Internal server Error \(er)")
                        break
                    }
                })
            }
```

but on server side i'm getting as :

```
["product": [
  {
    "product_id" : "1"
  },
  {
    "quantity" : "6"
  },
  {
    "product_id" : "3"
  },
  {
    "quantity" : "7"
  },
  {
    "product_id" : "4"
  },
  {
    "quantity" : "1"
  }
]]
```

i have also tried

```
encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
```

then i got

```
["{\"product\":": {
  "{\"product_id\":1,\"quantity\":6},{\"quantity\":7,\"product_id\":3},{\"product_id\":4,\"quantity\":1}" : ""
}]
```

The input my API required is in format below:
product[0][product_id]:1
product[0][quantity]:6
product[1][product_id]:2
product[1][quantity]:6

[Postman example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12I-ieQPitg0cnTgmTpVh7TNzzZyVD0ao/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

1. Create Model

   ```
   struct Product {
       var product_id: Int
      var quantity : Int
   }
   ```
2. Populate model from your App - based on selection

   ```
   let product = Product.init(product_id: 1, quantity: 6)
   let product1 = Product.init(product_id: 2, quantity: 3)
   let product2 = Product.init(product_id: 4, quantity: 1)

   arrayProducts.append(product)
   arrayProducts.append(product1)
   arrayProducts.append(product2)
   ```
3. Before server call - make param as server requires.

   ```
       var parameters = [String: Any]()

       for (index, element) in arrayProducts.enumerated() {
           let dynamicProductIDKey = "product[\(index)][product_id]"
           let dynamicProductIDValue = element.product_id

           let dynamicProductQuantityKey = "product[\(index)][quantity]"
           let dynamicProductQuantityValue = element.quantity

           parameters[dynamicProductIDKey] = dynamicProductIDValue
           parameters[dynamicProductQuantityKey] = dynamicProductQuantityValue

       }
   ```

Now you can share parameters to server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try following dictionary

```
let dict = [
    "product[0][product_id]" : "1",
    "product[0][quantity]" : "6",
    "product[1][product_id]" : "2",
    "product[1][quantity]" : "6",
]
```